# Ajax user registration failing upon submission issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to implement an ajax modal signup form where users can register for the site. I have managed to get the login form working, but I am hitting a snag on registration. I took my login modal template as reference. Where did I go wrong?

**UPDATE** I've managed to get the database to register the user..and I've updated the code below. Few things now.

1. The page doesnt redirect to homepage upon registration
2. It doesnt have the user logged in when I do refresh the page
3. Checking phpMyAdmin, the password the user inputs is not what is found in the database (a random string of text is there)
4. When I use this random string of text OR the password that they registered with, the login fails.

**My HTML.**

```
<div id="signup-body" class="toggleMe">
                    <form class="form" id="signupform" role="form" name="signupform" action="" method="post">
                        <p class="status"></p> <!-- testing the status -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="signup-name">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="signupname" name="signup-name" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Form Group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="signup-email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="signupemail" name="signup-email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="signup-password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="signuppassword" name="signup-password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Form Group -->

                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary signup-modal-button" value="Sign Up">
                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' ); ?>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Perform AJAX login on form submit
    $('form#signupform').on('submit', function(e){
        $('form#signup p.status').show().text('Sending user info, please wait...');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>",
            data: {
                action: 'register_user', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username': $('form#signupform #signupname').val(),
                                'email': $('form#signupform #signupemail').val(),
                'password': $('form#signupform #signuppassword').val(),
                'security': $('form#signupform #security').val() },

            success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                $('form#signup p.status').text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true){
                    document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
                }
            },error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }

        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

**In the functions.php**

```
function ajax_signup_init(){

wp_register_script('ajax-signup-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/ajax-signup-script.js', array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script('ajax-signup-script');

wp_localize_script( 'ajax-signup-script', 'ajax_signup_object', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'redirecturl' => home_url(),
    'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
));

// Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX

}
add_action('init', 'ajax_signup_init');

function ajax_signup(){

    // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce','security');

    // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_email'] = $_POST['email'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;


    $user_signup = wp_insert_user( $info);

    if (!is_wp_error($user_signup) ){
         echo "User created : ". $user_signup;
    }

    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_register_user', 'ajax_signup' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_register_user', 'ajax_signup' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax callback function should be like below.

```
        function ajax_signup(){

            // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
            check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce','security');

            // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
            $info = array();
            $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
            $info['user_email'] = $_POST['email'];
            $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
            $info['remember'] = true;


            $user_signup = wp_insert_user( $info);  

            if (!is_wp_error($user_signup) ){
                echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Sign up successful, redirecting...')));
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
            }
            wp_set_current_user($user_signup);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($user_signup);
            die();
        }

        add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_login', 'ajax_login' );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_login', 'ajax_login' );
```

You have to add these two in your code.

```
   wp_set_current_user($user_signup);
   wp_set_auth_cookie($user_signup);
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to use the full path of a element with `id` attribute with jQuery, doing so makes it harder and uses more resources. You can use:

```
data: {
    action: 'register_user', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
    'username': $('#signupname').val(),
    'email': $('#signupemail').val(),
    'password': $('#signuppassword').val(),
    'security': $('#security').val() 
},
```

And if you do have more elements with the same id, stop what you doing and read about the id attribute.

Next, in your success callback you use the value `data.loggedin` although you never echoed a valid JSON output on `ajax_signup` function. That's probably why there is no redirect.

For why the data is not being written correctly to database, use a `var_dump($_POST)` and check for the response on Developer Tools' network tab. You may want to open this before the request to make sure it's captured.

Last, I may be wrong since I don't use Wordpress for a long time, but since you used only `wp_insert_user`, there is no way you return a user logged, or at least it's not documented: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_user/

Comment: thanks for the help so far, I've edited my `data` section. I'm still sort of new to this so I'm not quite sure how to add an echo for `ajax_signup` or where exactly to code in the `var_dump` Would you be able to help?

Comment: The `var_dump($_POST)` should be added in `ajax_signup` function body.

Comment: OK I put ` echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POST, true) . "</pre>";` into the `ajax_signup` since the `var_dump` just made my localhost go to white screen. What exactly am I looking for on network tab? I see the admin-ajax php is called whenever I click submit

Comment: Click on the request, and you should see another frame with four new tabs. One of them is "Response" what is shown there is exactly what is sent to your success callback, or any other respective callback depending on HTTP code. There, check if POST variables are correct and if their keys are the same you're using to add a user.

Comment: ah I see. Yes looking at the Response tab I see my array with all correct inputs and variables here

Comment: @JordanLewallen I'll have to continue with you later, my server is being attacked apparently, but check if wp_insert_user doesn't add a hash to your password somehow. Despite that, the rest is really echo json_encode(array("foo"=> "var"))` so you can really see the object in the success callback.